# Apache Passenger handle 'www' in url

Tags: apache, passenger

I've an application deployed to EC2 using passenger and apache2.

I've registered a domain (not with AWS) and have two 'A' records pointing to my instance's elastic IP

1. appname.com.
2. *.appname.com.

In my apache2.conf file (below), I've got `ServerName appname.com`

The application is working perfectly when you type appname.com into a browser. But if you put www.appname.com into the browser, you just get the default apache page.

Does anyone know what I put in `ServerName` to handle both? I've tried adding another ServerName line under the first but it doesn't work.

Thanks for looking

> **/etc/apache2/apache2.conf**

```
<IfModule mod_passenger.c>
     PassengerRoot /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-5.0.6
     PassengerDefaultRuby /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1
</IfModule>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName appname.com
  # !!! Be sure to point DocumentRoot to 'public'!
  DocumentRoot /home/ubuntu/projects/appname/public
  ErrorLog /home/ubuntu/projects/appname/log/error.log
  RailsEnv development

  <Directory /home/ubuntu/projects/appname/public>
     # This relaxes Apache security settings.
     AllowOverride all
     Require all granted
     # MultiViews must be turned off.
     Options -MultiViews
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it thanks to [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/278667/apache2-phusion-passenger-either-different-port-or-all-pages-overridden/278720#278720) post (shame you can't thank on the other stack sites using your stackoverflow reputation)

Under

```
ServerName appname.com
```

you put

```
AliasName www.appname.com
```

or even better

```
AliasName *.appname.com
```